# react-script 4.0.3 showing Module parse failed: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:56)
```

File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('/home/emon/Documents/Foysal's Personal Directory/PersonalProjects/utmdb/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
> | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `'` character in your directory's name `Foysal's Personal Directory` can trigger this issue, create your project in another folder.

changing my folder-name to something(SoftwareDevt) without the character worked for me

Comment: It's working when I try with 4.0.1 in the same directory.